# How to dynamically unpack a list as you create?

Tags: python

How would I create a list element from function call?

Not sure if this is possible, but I've tried to create a list element from a function when i create the list as i'm not sure of the elements up until runtime

So I have tried this:

```
>>>> def make_list_element():
        return 'd, e'
```

If i then try to create a list and call the function at the same time :

```
>>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', make_list_element().split(", ")]
```

And I get:

```
>>> a
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e']]
```

How could I achieve this:

```
>>> a
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Preferably in the same statement as I create the list.

Many thanks

Comment: Please always use the generic python tag, if your question is about a specific python version, then optionally include a version-specific tag

Comment: If you function returns a list, then you won't need the `split()` function just the asterisk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python3, you can simply unpack the returned list like so:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', *make_list_element().split(", ") ]
```

If you're on Python2, you will have to concatenate or extend the list:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c'] + make_list_element().split(", ")
```

or

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a.extend(make_list_element().split(", "))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this errors with 

`>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', *make_list_element().split(", ")]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = ['a', 'b', 'c', *make_list_element().split(", ")]
`

Comment: This seems to work though 

`a = ['a', 'b', 'c'] + make_list_element().split(", ")`

Thanks